# React table filtering & responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create table using **react** that should have following functionality

- search filter using name filter
- dropdown filter using states
- ascending and descending order sorting when clicking on the column header.
- Make table responsive

You can assume following data - 
var data = [{name: 'zz',state: 'ua'},{name: 'hhj',state: 'op'}]

I've search following react plugins for table functionality -

- React Griddle (https://github.com/griddlegriddle/griddle)
- React data grid (https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid)

While looking into stars at the github, It seems **react griddle** is better but **What would be best plugin to achieve the goal** ?

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive", to screen size? And what is "dropdown filter using states"? FWIW, I have used `Ag-grid` with some success in the past, but for use with Redux the one that did the job was `React-virtualized`.

Comment: Try both and do the evaluation based on your real scenario? From what I can tell, I tested a lot of table engines and ended up writing my own engine ;)

Comment: which one did you use finally?

Answer (score 9):

I spent the day reading about all the plugins available with more than 100 stars or forks. I've been using `react-table` the last months but it hasn't been updated in months, his creator wrote in an issue that he's planning to release the upgrade in 6 months (too late for some of us).

The requirement more difficult to find is "make table responsive". Only two of then fulfilled this requirement: [`react-data-grid`](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) and [`tabulator`](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator). Both repositories were created more than 2 years ago, have more than 1000 commits and have been updated during the last week.

`react-data-grid`: Its not fully responsive but at least it keep the first column fixed, it has a very good demo and documentation written specifically for React

`tabulator`: Its  full responsive with an option called *Responsive Layout Collapsed List* but its documentation is not written specifically for React, since it can be used with Vue and Angular too.

**TL:DR;** For an advanced front-end dev I would recommend `tabulator`, for a junior developer I would recommend `react-data-grid` to not struggle creating your tables

Comment: There is now a react wrapper for Tabulator, have a look at https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator#readme

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried looking into ReactTable?

ReactTable tables have built-in functionality for ascending / descending order-sorting when clicking on the column header.

In terms of creating a search filter, it has that functionality as well.

You may have to build the dropdown filter yourself but I believe ReactTable should provide you with a base to complete most of what you are looking to do.

React-table doesn't offer responsive width, though.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You said that "ReactTable tables are responsive to screen size" but the [demos](http://react-table.js.org/#/story/simple-table) seem to just add horizontal scrollbars on narrow windows. Can you point me at an example of a responsive implementation? Thanks!

Comment: I used [react-super-responsive-table](https://github.com/ua-oira/react-super-responsive-table) with react-table to turn the tables rendered with react-table responsive pretty easy. I used the new Table, Thead, Tr, Td and Th responsive components along with react-table without problems.

Comment: Provided links are not working please update your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can check my table implementation that build on material-ui library.

https://github.com/mbrn/material-table

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many solutions, however, the easiest one I had got working, was react-table.

Install React-table using npm - `npm i react-table`.
 Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table.

**React table Custom filtering solution - This is how I did a custom filter with react-table.**.

```
<ReactTable
          data={data}
          filterable
          defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
            String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "First Name",
                  accessor: "firstName",
                  filterMethod: (filter, row) =>
                    row[filter.id].startsWith(filter.value) &&
                    row[filter.id].endsWith(filter.value)
                },

{
                  Header: "Over 21",
                  accessor: "age",
                  id: "over",
                  Cell: ({ value }) => (value >= 21 ? "Yes" : "No"),
                  filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
                    if (filter.value === "all") {
                      return true;
                    }
                    if (filter.value === "true") {
                      return row[filter.id] >= 21;
                    }
                    return row[filter.id] < 21;
                  },
                  Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) =>
                    <select
                      onChange={event => onChange(event.target.value)}
                      style={{ width: "100%" }}
                      value={filter ? filter.value : "all"}
                    >
                      <option value="all">Show All</option>
                      <option value="true">Can Drink</option>
                      <option value="false">Can't Drink</option>
                    </select>
                }
```